# Kibana visualisation using histogram field type

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I setup a index with mapping like this

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp":           { "type" : "date"},
      "data_historgram":     { "type" : "histogram"},
      "metric":              { "type" : "keyword" }
    }
}
```

and sent data to it like this

```
{
  metric: DelayMs,
  data_histogram : {
      values : [1176, 2015, 2015, 816, 1967],
      counts : [8, 17, 8, 7, 6]
   }
}
```

So far so good, but i want to then visualise the data. The `values` in this metric are a delay in milliseconds between request and response. The corresponding `count` is the number of reported IoT devices with this value.

Using Kibana is it possible to plot a vertical bar chart for each value/count combination in the histogram fields data.. i.e. so the value for 1176 would have a vertical height of 8 ? And there would be a bar per value/count... or stacked.

thanks
fLo